# Multiple 404 error on TFS 2018 instance

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Seeing multiple 404 error on TFS 2018 instance.

No bigger changes have been made after installation, Only action done is one administrator who don't have access to DB just created one collection on TFS server but it didn't show up in TFS administration console.

while trying to delete the team project and an offline agent(removed from Build server)  seeing 404 errors

How do we resolve this issue ?

Comment: 404 errors when doing **what**? Is this an upgrade, or a fresh installation?

Comment: " `but it didn't show up in TFS administration console.`" So, how did you try to delete the Collection? 404 error means not found. Could you provide more information to clarify the question?

Comment: I'm trying delete it on TFS server(Browser), it was just created on tfs server(browser) but not on TFS administration console(windows server)

Comment: @santhosh No any way to delete a collection via browser. Do you mean delete a team project from browser? Whatever you need to provide the reproduce steps and any other related information for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Yes it is Team Project

Comment: Seeing below errors message in event view

DisposableCollection<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.SignalR.ISignalRApplicationExtension> was not disposed!

Comment: @santhosh Please make sure you have the permission to delete the team project. the user should be in `Project Collection Administrators group`. See [Quickstart: Add administrators, set permissions at the project-level or project collection-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=vsts) to set permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue.

The thing causing 404 erros is **URL SCAN** that was installed along with IIS.

it is blocking certain requests on TFS including deletion,group membership and some css(which caused change in TFS user management view)

Once after removing this from the IIS, TFS came back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, since the issue was resolved, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have the correct permission to delete the team project.

To delete a team project, the user should be in `Project Collection Administrators group`. See [Quickstart: Add administrators, set permissions at the project-level or project collection-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?view=vsts) to set permissions.

Besides, you can also try to delete the team project with `TFSDeleteProject` command:

```
TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss] /collection:URL TeamProjectName
```

> **To use the TFSDeleteProject command, you must be a member of the **Team Foundation Administrators** security group or the **Project Administrators** security group. For more information, see Set
>   administrator permissions for Team Foundation Server.**

See [Delete a team project with TFSDeleteProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd?view=tfs-2018) for details.